# How to know which platform thread is carrying the virtual thread?

Tags: project-loom, java-19

Is there a way to know which platform thread is carrying the current virtual thread or pin a virtual thread to a platform thread and get its threadlocal in JDK19? I want to reuse some objects in virtual threads, something like sync.Pool in Golang.

Comment: I hope, they’ll find effective ways to prevent people from doing this.

Comment: I am not so satisfied with the ThreadLocal in virtual threads, I understand that it's for compatibility with older codes, but I think Threadlocal just shouldn't be used in virtual threads since Thread object is same for platform thread and virtual thread. I think there should be a API for virtual thread to look for its carrier platform thread's threadlocal, and virtual thread's own threadlocal should always be disabled.

Comment: That would pervert the entire concept of *thread local*. If an object is handed out to multiple virtual threads simultaneously, because they share the same carrier thread, the object is *not* thread local. “Solving” this problem by pinning the virtual thread is equal to disabling the virtual threads feature completely. Object pooling is a bad idea anyway. Reusing resources like database connections, is a different thing, but this works better with explicit acquire and release operations, independent of the identity of threads.

Comment: I mean the virtual thread should be able to get its carrier thread's threadlocal in its Runnable logic, since a paltform thread could only executing one single virtual thread at the same time.

Comment: Also why is object pooling a bad idea? I have a lot of constantly used, fixed size objects, and I want them to be reusable and GC-free, I can't imagine another way to realize it other than pooling objects.

Comment: There’s enough documentation and articles accumulated over the last twenty years explaining why the tenacious myth that pooling or any kind of manual memory management was better than sophisticated garbage collection implementations does not hold. Even looking up the existing object in a thread local variable is more expensive than a straight-forward allocation, unless there are actual non-memory resources or computational intense initializations involved. And it seems you don’t understand the purpose of virtual thread at all. They may give the carrier thread to another virtual thread anytime.

Comment: So you are saying that in log4j2 their Garbage-free Steady State Logging is just useless? netty's PooledBytebuf by your opinion is useless? Language without garbage-collection is   garbage? @Holger

Comment: Funny that you mention log4j. Do you remember [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j#Log4Shell_vulnerability)? A library that opens connections to other servers depending on the contents of the logging string surely has other problems than garbage collection. Even performance-wise, as network traffic surely is slower than any shenanigans you can make with heap objects. I’m not discussing other programming languages. Just that in Java, your thread local pooling will be slower than ordinary object allocation, again, in Java. Might not apply to netty’s *native* buffer though.

Comment: @刘希晨 This was a difficult tradeoff.  We did explore the "just make ThreadLocal not work in virtual threads" theory, but the result was (not surprisingly) that a significant fraction of real-world code would then not work in virtual threads either, since so many popular libraries use ThreadLocal (sometimes in surprising ways.)  So support for ThreadLocal is a forced move for compatibility.  You can create VTs that do not support TLs, though, and we are working on alternatives to TL that are more VT-friendly.

Comment: There is no way to access the carrier thread, by design.  If you think you need it, you are almost certainly mistaken.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I think they can't expect the code using TL would work well in virtual threads at all, eventually code must have to be rewritten or a lot of memory would be wasted for TL. Maybe ExtendLocal would help solve the problem.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I have tested using ArrayBlockingQueue for a object-pool providing reuseable StringBuilder for virtual threads other than new StringBuilder() every time, it turns out to be much faster and having no GC pressure, it would be even better if you guys could invent something like sync.Pool in Golang to avoiding lock cost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [JEP 425](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425), the spec for virtual threads in JDK 19:

> The identity of the carrier is unavailable to the virtual thread.

So, no, I don't think there is any way to determine which platform thread is running a virtual thread (i.e. in Java code; there are ways to observe this via tooling such as the Java Flight Recorder).

Pinning a thread is something to be avoided [1], and so I doubt there is any way to explicitly do that. From the same JEP 425:

> a running virtual thread is logically independent of its current carrier

Given the above quote, and various presentations/documentation to that effect, I would be very surprised if there were a way to pin a thread explicitly via an API.

Finally, regarding ThreadLocals, there is a discussion at [2] where the Project Loom team mentions the dangers of caching expensive objects in ThreadLocals (note that they do ***not*** mention access to the underlying platform thread). I'm not familiar with the Go construct but you may want to consider [JEP 429](https://www.infoq.com/news/2022/09/extent-local-variables-java/) on Extent-Locals.

[1] - see 36m20s [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQ6EpIk7KgY), a presentation by the Project Loom team

[2] - see 35m01s [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQ6EpIk7KgY), the same presentation by the Project Loom team

Comment: From my understanding about Extend-Locals, guys developing loom wants us to bind some variables to a specific object and then pass it through functions, and we can get variables from that specific object, is that right?